# Check which rows in a data.table are identical

Tags: r, data.table

I need a solution that shows me which rows are identical but I can't find a clever solution (a solution without a bunch of complex loops). I would prefer a `data.table` solution.
What I want to have is a list with line numbers that have the identical entries.

An example:

```
library(data.table)
Data <- data.table(A = c("a", "a", "c"), 
                   B = c("A", "A", "B"))
```

The first and the second line are identical.
My desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2

[[2]]
[1] 3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is something quick and dirty:

```
Data[, .(.I, .GRP), by = .(A, B)][, list(split(I, GRP))]$V1
```

Could be simplified to:

```
Data[, .(list(.I)), by = .(A, B)]$V1
```

Comment: That is really great, I wonder why I did not know `.GRP` until now. Thank you vermy much!

Comment: That's the final code I am using now: `Data[, .(.I, .GRP), .(A, B)] %>% 
  split(by = "GRP") %>% 
  map("I")`

Comment: @TobiSonne Good you know  about `.GRP` but you could also do without it (see updated post).

Answer (score 0):

That was my solution until sindri_baldur came up with a better solution:

```
Data.unique <- unique(Data)
Data.unique[, G := .I]
Data[, I := .I]
Data.full <- 
  merge(Data,
        Data.unique,
        by = c("A", "B"))

Data.full %>% 
  split(by = "G") %>% 
  map(~ .x[, I])
```